# How to reference images within an HTML file (when running on a local host)

Tags: html

My goal is to create an HTML file that renders an image.  I'd like to zip the project and share it with someone, who would then run it on **their local machine**.

Let's assume that I have an `index.html` file that references an image named `infographic.png`.  This `infographic.png` file is saved in an `assets` folder.

My file structure is:

```
C://Users/name/Desktop/projects/project_2/index.html
C://Users/name/Desktop/projects/project_2/assets/infographic.png
```

When I use JetBrains Webstorm to inspect the webpage, I see that the `infographic.png` file renders as expected.  However, when I navigate to the `index.html` file on my machine via Windows Explorer and double-click the `index.html` file, I see that the `infographic.png` is not rendering (only the alt text is rendering).

Originally, my code was:

```
<img src="./assets/infographic.png" alt="Infographic of Salary Data">
```

**(notice the single dot in the path)**

Then, I changed it to a double dot (..) in the file path:

```
<img src="../assets/infographic.png" alt="Infographic of Salary Data">
```

And, that seems to have resolved the issue.  The image renders as expected.

**Question:**  Is the double dot (..) the right way to reference this file?  Is there another way?

Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

**UPDATE:**

The `index.html` file looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT"
          crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 id="Example">Example</h1>

<hr>

<div class="container">
    <div id="title" class="row">
        <h4>Example</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 justify-content-center">
            <img src="./assets/infographic.png" alt="Infographic of Salary Data">
        </div>
        <div id="analysis" class="col-6">
            <h4>Analysis</h4>

            <p>this is some text commentary...</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using `./assets/infographic.png` is (usually) correct as a relative path from the `index.html` file location. However, the "base url" might have been changed. Please [edit] your question to include the source code of your HTML file as a [mcve], which shows the problem you have.

Comment: The added source code in your edit does not reproduce the error/problem you describe. When tried it will resolve to the correct path `./assets/infographic.png`, relative to the location of the `index.html` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/ means the root of the current drive;
./ means the current directory;
../ means the parent of the current directory.
```

The other way you can reference the file is with the absolute path.  Google relative versus absolute path.  I'm sure W3 has a tutorial.  If you are wondering why people are trying to close this question it's because a simple google or stackoverflow search would reveal the answer.  The more you help yourself the more other people will help you.